# What does a semicolon before an equal sign mean?

Tags: c, syntax

My book has the following piece of code. Is it some sort of misprint? I haven't been able to find anything online.

```
StackNodePtr tempPtr; = *topPtr;
```

Comment: It means syntax error

Comment: In this case the typo is probably leaving the semicolon when they added an initialization to the declaration. Best guess is they meant `StackNodePtr tempPtr = *topPtr;` (without the internal semi-colon).

Comment: What book? Most (good) books have a link to a web page that lists corrections. Check the preface.

Comment: If you try to compile it and it fails, it is not valid - simple test, what it means is irrelevant if your compiler cannot parse it.

Comment: The precise code but corrected appears at http://www.alfonsofuggetta.org/informatica/wp-content/uploads/12_StruttureDatiDinamiche.pdf and also here https://repl.it/@sphan001/Ch-12-Ex-of-Simple-Stack-Program  but neither reveal what book it is from (but chapter 12 I guess).  Always a good idea to cite your sources.

Answer (score 2):

It is a misprint. There is absolutely no way that could compile.

Comment: Thank you. That had me wondering since I'm pretty sure I've seen that same error somewhere else in the book.

Comment: @Impasse Usually each book (even of non-first edition) has many typos.:)